# EF6 not generating table joins as expected

Tags: join, entity-framework-6

I have an abstract `Entity` class from which all my entities derive.  This base class has `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` properties, both of type `AppUser`.  Since `AppUser` also inherits from `Entity`, I am wondering if this circularity is confusing EF.  Here's my class definition:

```cs
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public AppUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public AppUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

When I call `context.Users.ToArray()`, it returns this:

```sql
IsActive Identifier FirstName LastName MiddleName Id 
False    ee224559   bob       jones               1  
False    ee224559   bob       jones               1  
False    ee224559   bob       jones               1  
False    ee224559   bob       jones               1  
False    dheyue3    mary      smith    sue        21 
False    dheyue3    sarah     jones               22
```

Here's the SQL it's generating:

```sql
SELECT 
"Extent1"."FIRSTNAME" AS "FIRSTNAME",
"Extent2"."FIRSTNAME" AS "CREATEDBY",
"Extent3"."FIRSTNAME" AS "MODIFIEDBY"
FROM   "MYSCHEMA"."APPUSER" "Extent1"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "MYSCHEMA"."APPUSER" "Extent2" ON 
("Extent2"."CREATEDBY_ID" IS NOT NULL) AND ("Extent1"."ID" = "Extent2"."CREATEDBY_ID")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "MYSCHEMA"."APPUSER" "Extent3" ON 
("Extent3"."MODIFIEDBY_ID" IS NOT NULL) AND ("Extent1"."ID" = "Extent3"."MODIFIEDBY_ID");
```

Here's what I want it to generate:

```sql
SELECT 
"Extent1"."FIRSTNAME" AS "FIRSTNAME",
"Extent2"."FIRSTNAME" AS "CREATEDBY",
"Extent3"."FIRSTNAME" AS "MODIFIEDBY"
FROM   "MYSCHEMA"."APPUSER" "Extent1"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "MYSCHEMA"."APPUSER" "Extent2" ON 
("Extent1"."CREATEDBY_ID" IS NOT NULL) AND ("Extent2"."ID" = "Extent1"."CREATEDBY_ID")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "MYSCHEMA"."APPUSER" "Extent3" ON 
("Extent1"."MODIFIEDBY_ID" IS NOT NULL) AND ("Extent3"."ID" = "Extent1"."MODIFIEDBY_ID");
```

I can't bold text in a code block, so notice how the `Extent` qualifiers are swapped in the join.  How can I get them to be generated like in my second SQL example?

**Update**

This is the code I originally had in my `OnModelCreating` method:

```sql
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasOptional(x => x.CreatedBy).WithOptionalDependent();
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasOptional(x => x.ModifiedBy).WithOptionalDependent();
```

Changing it to this per answerer's recommendation worked:

```sql
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasOptional(x => x.CreatedBy).WithMany();
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasOptional(x => x.ModifiedBy).WithMany();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something has to be wrong with the model configuration.

I've created the following class:

```
public class AppUser : Entity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

added it to my test `DbContext` (latest EF6.1.3):

```
public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
```

and w/o any additional configuration got an exception

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'EFTest.AppUser' and 'EFTest.AppUser'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

So I added the following in my `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.CreatedBy).WithMany();
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.ModifiedBy).WithMany();
```

and now the migration ran successfully. Interestingly, I've created another `Entity` derived entity and it doesn't require such configuration - EF determined correctly the same as with the above configuration, so the issue seems to be with self referencing.

Finally, executing the following LINQ query:

```
var query = db.AppUsers
    .Select(u => new {  u.FirstName, CreatedBy = u.CreatedBy.FirstName, ModifiedBy = u.ModifiedBy.FirstName })
    .ToList();
```

generated the SQL as expected:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName1], 
    [Extent3].[FirstName] AS [FirstName2]
    FROM   [dbo].[AppUsers] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AppUsers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CreatedBy_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AppUsers] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ModifiedBy_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
```

Shortly, check your configuration and/or EF version.

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly.  See update to end of my question